# Is there any way that I could "array" a group of pictureBox to use in a for statement?

Tags: c#

I would like to use 1 `for` statement for all of my pictureBox that I am using as coins for this simple game I am doing in my programming classes. If my pictureBox1 intersects with one of the other pictureBox, an array type variable will add 1 to the variable initiated in the `for` to deny access to the `if` statement that puts the pictureBox invisible and then adds a point to the counter (label).

```
 for (int o = 0; o < picture.Length; o++)
             {
                 if ((pictureBox1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pictureBox2.Bounds) == true) && (picture[o] == 0))
                 {
                     pictureBox2.Visible = false;

                     picture[o]++;
                     if ((pictureBox2.Visible == false) && (picture[o] == 1))
                     {
                         label1.Text = "Points: " + i++;
                     }
                 }
             }
```

This is the current code.
I want the array `picture` to receive the value 1.
That array is declared like this:

```
int[] picture = new int[] { 0 };
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which part of the problem are you having trouble with?

Comment: @mjwills i just want to know if it's possible to array the pictureBoxes just to make it easier to add pictureBoxes and to not make many for statements

Comment: You can make an array of anything, so yeah why not